# Python 3 e Tkinter: barra de progresso não atualiza durante execução do script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Olá.
Estou criando um conversor de layout usando Python 3.6.4 e Tkinter.

Entre outras coisas a GUI deve ter uma barra de progresso que atualiza seu valor a cada interação do processo de conversão, por exemplo, a cada linha processada do arquivo que está sendo convertido, a barra de progresso deve ser atualizada.

O problema que estou enfrentando é que o "programa" trava enquanto está executando a conversão e a barra não é atualizada. A barra somente atualiza no final da operação de conversão.

A parte básica do script é esta (retirei tudo que não é relevante e deixei apenas o essencial para ver onde está o problema ou onde estou errando):

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(600, 400))

        self.progress = StringVar()
        self.progress.set(0)
        self.progressBar = Progressbar(self.Window, maximum=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, variable=self.progress)
        self.progressBar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E)

        self.startButton = Button(self.Window, text='Iniciar', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def start(self):
        for t in range(0,100):
            self.progress.set(t)
            sleep(0.1)

    def run(self):
        self.Window.mainloop()
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui = Gui()
    sys.exit(Gui.run())
```

Sou iniciante no Python porém tenho longa experiência (quinze anos) com PHP e etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo é que o tkinter, (bem como outros toolkits gráficos em várias linguagens, como GTK, Qt, etc...) rodam numa única thread.  Um programa gráfico tem sempre um laço principal, que é onde o framework tem o código para coletar todos os eventos que chegam a aplicação, e chamar as funções correspondentes para que sejam processados.

Dai você configura sua aplicação para quando o botão for pressionado, o método `start` deve ser chamado - e passa o controle para o `mainloop` do Tkinter. Quando o botão é pressionado, o tkinter pega o evento do mouse vindo do sistema operacional, cria o evento interno, e chama a função start -- e essa, por sua vez *não devolve* o controle para o tkinter. Em vez disso ela faz 100 atualizações no `self.progress`, e só depois disso devolve o controle. Quando a `start` acaba de rodar é que o tkinter vai processar todos os seus eventos internos de  `set` da progressbar.

Mais ainda, em cada chamada ao `time.sleep`, o sue programa fica parado, sem responder a eventos externos nem nada - por que o códgio que faz isso está no laço principal.

E como arrumar? Simples: em nenhum programa gráfico você chama o `tine.sleep` ou função equivalente (a não ser que ela seja integrada ao framework). No caso do tkinter, o correto é fazeruma chamada ao `Window.after` dizendo um método para ser chamado dali a tantos milissegundos. Você faz esse agendamento, e devolve o controle para o laço principal do tkinter.
Claro que o estado da barra de progresso deve ficar armazenado em algum lgar entre uma chaamda em outra - como você já está dentro de uma classe, é só usar um atributo específico para isso.

```
class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.progress_count = 0


    def start(self):
        self.progress.set(self.progress_count)
        self.progress_count += 1
        if self.progress_count < 100:
             self.Window.after(100, self.start)
```

Comment: Quanto ao uso de time.sleep(), usei apenas para o código de exemplo, mas ele não é usado no código de produção.

Comment: sim - mas você entendeu a resposta? Você chama a função que atualiza a progressbar a um intervalo de tempo fixo, com o metodo `.after`  - e ele verifica o atributo de "quanto está completo" (mas não vai atualizar ele, como nesse exemplo)

Comment: O erro é você não pode fazer um laço direto para atualizar a propriedade - tem que retornar ao mainloop para que o trabalho possa andar.

Comment: captei a essência do que você colocou (eu acho), a questão é que, o código que tenho é um conversor de layout. Ele pega alguns dados (diretório de entrada, diretório de saída, formato da conversão), e quando o usuário clica no botão converter, o python deve pegar arquivo por arquivo do diretório de entrada, ler linha por linha do arquivo e converter isso num determinado formato e gravar; e ainda: a cada arquivo processado (ou poderia ser a cada linha) atualizar a barra de progresso. Não estou conseguindo visualizar como fazer isso com Tk.after(). Tenho que estudar mais o assunto!

Comment: nesse caso, acho que acaba ficando melhor chamar o `update_idletasks` mesmo após cada x linhas.  Apesar do que eu escrevi, em python temos que ter em mente que " practicality beats purity". 
Agora, o que você pode fazer é manter as coisas separadas: mantenha um método de 4 =/5 linahs só pra atualizar a barra de progresso, como esse do exemplo, usandoo  `after`  _e_  no seu processamento principal use o  `;update_idletasks` - dessa forma você não precisa misturar a lógica de atualizar a barra de progressos com a lógica das tarefas do seu aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Após horas de pesquisa na última noite, encontrei algo que também solucionou o problema: usar self.Window.update_idletasks() dentro do loop.

> Calls all pending idle tasks, without processing any other events. This can be used to carry out geometry management and redraw widgets if necessary, without calling any callbacks.

Assim, o código final (com alguns pequenos ajustes) ficou assim

```
class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.geometry('{0}x{1}'.format(600, 400))

        self.progress = DoubleVar()
        self.progress.set(0)
        self.progressBar = Progressbar(self.Window, maximum=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, variable=self.progress)
        self.progressBar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W + E)

        self.startButton = Button(self.Window, text='Iniciar', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def start(self):
        for t in range(0, 100, 20):
            self.progress.set(t)
            print(t)
            self.Window.update_idletasks()
            sleep(2)
        self.progress.set(100)
        print('Fim...')

    def run(self):
        self.Window.mainloop()
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Gui = Gui()
    sys.exit(Gui.run())
```

Comment: Ao fazer isso, você "rouba" a função do laço principal do tkinter, (Mainloop)  - não é a forma correta de fazer. Faz mais sentido fazer isso num programa muito especializado em quf você de fat otenha um laço principal (mainloop) seu. - e chame o `update_idletasks` para o tkinter faer todo o processamento. Mas se o seu programa não está construído dessa forma, você deve manter cada callback simples, com pouco código, e sem laços -  e agendar a sua re-execução por meio de eventos (como por exemoplo, com o `.after`). Esse é o paradigma não só do tkinter, mas de todas as libs gráficas.

Comment: Ambas as soluções funcionaram, porém não posso dizer quais tiveram melhor desempenho (não fiz benchmark), porém vou ver se adapto o código de produção para fazer uso do .after.

Comment: A diferenã de performance dos dois modos é negligível - nem faz sentido se falar nisso ao se usar um toolkit gráfico em uma linguagem de muito alto nívle como Python. A diferença é mais semântica: deixar  o tkinter funcionar como foi planejado (que é executar seu mainloop e coreografar seus eventos) ou tentar assumir o lugar desse laço principal, sem haver necessidade e sem saber de todas as tarefas dele.